# Getting missing values from in clause

Tags: mysql

I have to find all those records for which I provide ids, so here is my query

```
SELECT * FROM `inf_company` where id IN(25523,25511,25448,28094,25243.....)
```

I provide 500 Ids in above query but it give me 200 records. I want to find rest of missing 300 records.

I want to see all those ids in my list which is not shown in result. How could be the query for that?

Comment: Is it problem in PMA or your project? 
Сheck the settings. Try add LIMIT 0, 500

Comment: Are you sure the other 300 ids exists in your table?

Comment: Build a (temporary) table of the desired ids and join it on to this table.

Comment: I want to see all those in my list

Comment: @user3244721: No, they don't.

Comment: Where does that list of ids come from in the first place? I doubt you have written them manually, right? If they come from another table, can't you LEFT JOIN from there? (Oh... and please edit the title... as it is it's absolutely meaningless)

Comment: use an OUTER JOIN when the condition is large as the query doesn't have to look up the "IN" condition. OR build a temporary table that has matched values and later join to this table. This table will have s single column table.

Comment: I have this list in excel sheet

Comment: can you give sample id which is not include in your preferred result. then query it 
SELECT * FROM inf_company where id = 12345
if it returns a value.

Comment: there are 500 ids,few of them i showed in my question...only 200 returns a value

Comment: You mean, the table contains exact 500 rows?

Comment: Frazz is right - your title is very misleading.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could write a `union` for the `id` fields and `left outer join` to get actual result:

```
select id
,      case
       when i1.id is not null
       then 'EXISTING'
       else 'NON-EXISTING'
       end
       status
from   ( select 25523 id union select 25511 union select 25448 /* etc, etc */ ) x
left
outer
join   inf_company i1
on     i1.id = x.id
```

You could also put the `id`s in a temporary table as suggested by [Strawberry](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1529673/strawberry). That will prevent the long list of `union` on `id`.

Comment: you asked me to write select 25523 id union select 25511 manually?should i write all 500 ids here?

Comment: Yes, just as in your current query, or preferably insert them in a temporary table. In this cases Excel may come in handy to fabricate the query.

Comment: @user3244721: Did this solve your issue? Need more help?

Comment: I am doing it manually in excel...by query it is not possible

Comment: What is your problem with this query?

Comment: Why not? A technical issue? I guess it is easy to do a 'replace all' on your current list. It will get you that list in no-time.